# What is this symbol next to the Pokémon's markings?

Tags: pokemon-ultra-sun-ultra-moon

[image: Poipole's status screen, with a "plus" symbol next to the markings]

I was scrolling through some Pokémon and I saw this symbol, but I have no idea what it is. What does this symbol mean?

Answer (score 2):

That would be the [Origin Marking](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Origin_marking).

From generation 6 onwards, a marker is placed next to any Pokemon that was raised in that generation.

The specific types of known origin markings thus far are:

- **The blue pentagon**: Used for the generation 6 games. Specifically, this is used for Pokemon from X and Y and Omega Ruby and Alpha Sapphire.
- **The black clover**: Used for the generation 7 games. Specifically, this is used for Pokemon from Sun and Moon, as well as Ultra Sun and Ultra Moon.
- **The Gameboy icon**: Used for Pokemon obtained through use of the Poke Transporter from the 3DS virtual console. This includes all remakes, for both generation 1 and 2.
- **The GO icon**: Used for Pokemon obtained from Pokemon GO. Only used in Let's Go Pikachu and Eevee so far.
- **No origin marking**: Used for Pokemon obtained in generation 3, 4 and 5, as these do not have origin markings.

In this case, the icon is the black clover, meaning the Pokemon was obtained in a generation 7 game.